# Magento 2: Remove 'low stock' label from product image

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, inventory, cataloginventory

I created a product and set 'Manage Stock' to no. But when i see a product on frontend, it shows a label 'Low Stock' on product thumbnail image. I do not want to show that label. I think there is an option in admin panel by which i can remove this label. Please help me to remove that label. 
[image]

Comment: could you pass the site URL

Comment: have you tried changing the value to 0 for setting `Notify for Quantity Below`

Comment: here is the URL: http://159.203.123.40/furniture-store/designs.html

Comment: URL throwing fatal error

Comment: Sorry for the error, the site is under development. I just added a screenshot of it.

Comment: As of now I don't find admin option for that , this can be in your theme options   but you can hide it using css .product-low-of-stock{display:none;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Turn off Low Stock Label via admin

```
Stores > Configuration > CleverSoft Themes > Theme Settings > Product Labels.
```

You may need to reindex the data and flush the cache

Let me know if you don't find the option

Thanks